# Why does my UIAlertView only appear after a delay?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

In example code below `UIAlertView` is show after delay, but i need display it immediately

```
//metoda zapisuje komentrz na serwerze
-(void) saveAction {

    UIAlertView *progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"imageGalleries.sendAction", @"") message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"alert.cancel", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [progressAlert addSubview:progressView];
    [progressAlert show];

    // some long performance instructions
}

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  [NavButton buttonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"sendImage.saveButtonTitle", @"") target:self action:@selector(saveAction)];
    progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(30.0f, 80.0f - 26, 225.0f, 10.0f)];
}
```

Why `UIAlertView` do not show immediately when I call `saveAction`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the “long performance instructions” following the alert code run on the main thread, they will block the alert from appearing. Read something about Cocoa run loops, that should make things more clear. (Essentially it could be said that all the UI instructions in your method are not performed immediately – they have to wait for the method to end, and then the main run loop picks them up and runs them.)

The code could better look like this:

```
- (void) startSomeLongOperation {
   [self createAndDisplayProgressSpinner];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0), ^{
       // …do something that takes long…
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissProgressSpinner];
       });
   });
}
```

This moves the long operation into background, so that the main thread can continue executing immediately.

Comment: My sentiment exactly. Perform long operations in the background. Notify the UI of the progress. the alert will display immediately and the operation can continue un-hindered. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for long lasting operations? It'll wrap those calls into separate threads for you and is very flexible from functionality and UI perspectives

Comment: This is better solution, but I must do with `UIAletView`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to call

```
  [progressAlert addSubview:progressView];
```

Aside from that, it really should just appear...

Answer (score 0):

If you show the alert in background thread, it will also have a delay.

Comment: When I asked the question I was beginner, now I can solve this kind of problems easily, but thank you for your answer.